# Incorrect updating integer values in the database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I' ve got an error when I attempt to update integer parameter in my database. If I changed it +1/-1 everything fine but changing it more (+5, +7, -4) save +1/-1 step only (example: change 5 to 10 and load it from DB - get 6).
Objects of drug_storage class are in a BindingList. I trace changes using ListChanged method. I use integer updown counter binded to drug_quantity parameter in two way mode; also use not mapped integer tag property of an object to store information about previous number of parameter. If counter change this parameter tag != parameter and DB updates

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>       
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding is_selected, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="checkbox" Margin="3" Checked="SelectComboBoxItem" Unchecked="SelectComboBoxItem" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding public_drug_name}" Margin="2" />
            <lc1:IntegerUpDown x:Name="iudQuantity" Minimum="1" Increment="1" Value="{Binding drug_quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="3" 
                               Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkbox, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ValueChanged="SelectComboBoxItem" />
        </StackPanel>            
    </DataTemplate>        
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding InfusionDrugList}" Margin="5" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDrug, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```

XAML.CS (if something in data template is clicked comboboxitem becomes selected and set value of SelectedDrug what triggers viewmodel code:

```
private void SelectComboBoxItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var v = FindVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>(sender as UIElement);
        if (v != null) { v.IsSelected = true; } // some checkboxes can become selected automatically at the moment of druglist loading and v would be null                      
    }
    public static T FindVisualParent<T>(UIElement element) where T : UIElement
    {
        UIElement parent = element; while (parent != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = parent as T; if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as UIElement;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void SelectComboBoxItem(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<int> e)
    {
        var v = FindVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>(sender as UIElement);
        if (v != null) { v.IsSelected = true; } // some updowns can become selected automatically at the moment of druglist loading and v would be null                      
    }
```

VIEW MODEL:
In Constructor:

```
 SelectedDrugs = new BindingList<drug_storage>();
        SelectedDrugs.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        SelectedDrugs.ListChanged += ProcessSelectedDrugCommands;
```

Later:

```
 ` public BindingList<drug_storage> SelectedDrugs { get; set; }
    private drug_storage selectedDrug;
    public drug_storage SelectedDrug
    {
        get { return selectedDrug; }
        set
        {
            selectedDrug = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            AddDrugForProcessing();
        }
    }
    private void AddDrugForProcessing()
    {
        if (SelectedDrug != null && !SelectedDrugs.Contains(SelectedDrug))
        {
            SelectedDrugs.Add(SelectedDrug);                
        }
    }        

 private void ProcessSelectedDrugCommands(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
.... //code to add and remove objects to DB

if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
            {
                int position = e.NewIndex;
                drug_storage drug = SelectedDrugs[position];
                if (drug.is_selected && drug.tag != drug.drug_quantity) //when user changed number in updown counter
                {
                    ChangeNumberOfDrugInDB(drug);
                }

 void ChangeNumberOfDrugInDB (drug_storage drug)
        {
            int procedure_id = SelectedInListProcedure.PMR_Id;
            int drug_id = SelectedDrug.drug_id;
            using (var db = new MainEntityModel())
            {
                var query = (from d in db.PMR_infusions_drugs
                             where d.PMR_Id == procedure_id && d.drug_id == drug_id
                             select d).Single();
                query.drug_quantity = drug.drug_quantity;
                db.SaveChanges();
                drug.tag = drug.drug_quantity;
            }                
        }}
```

I believe every time user change integerupdown binded to drug_quantity parameter it triggers DB update and then updates tag property but it looks like after inintial 1-integer-step updating drug.tag already becomes equal to final drug_quantity value. Can it be so?
Thanks

ADDITIONALY:

EF Class:

```
 public partial class drug_storage 
{       
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public drug_storage()
    {
        PMR_infusions_drugs = new HashSet<PMR_infusions_drugs>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int drug_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string drug_name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool is_selected { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    private int quantity = 1;

    [NotMapped]
    public int drug_quantity { get { return quantity; } set { quantity = value; } }

  
    [NotMapped]
    public int tag = 0;
    
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PMR_infusions_drugs> PMR_infusions_drugs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my shortness. Updated the question

Comment: "Can it be so?" - you can use the debugger to check for yourself.